# how to run my custom command from shell and print it into a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, binary

binary.txt is my input file and has the following contents.

```
1010011100010001010111001101111
0
10110000000101000000000000001
10100000011
1000000100
1111111111111111
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
```

while running the following command in the command line it works fine.

```
   printf "%032s\n" $(<binary.txt) | tr ' ' '0' >> t1.mif
```

But when i try to do the same using a script below , it gives me wrong values. Any suggestions.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=binary.txt
while read line;do
    printf "%032s\n" $line | tr ' ' '0' >> t1.mif
done < $FILE
```

thanks

Comment: *Which* values did it give you in both cases? You can use for example `xxd` to convert the result into something you can paste here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, you meant to to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=binary.txt
while read line;do
    printf "%032s\n" "$line" | tr ' ' '0' >> t1.mif
done < $FILE
```

Comment: And would also be better with `while ..; do ..; done < "$FILE" | tr ' ' '0' > t1.mif`.

Comment: Thanks I shall try that, I used $line without the quotations

Comment: @user2532296 Do you mean you'd actually prefer presenting variables without quotes? That's so wrong. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting.

Comment: Quotes around ``"$FILE"``, ``-r`` flag with read. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r